Vim: using a match (/ regexp) as a boolean to direct program flow
I'm developing a script for Vim to automatically update a "Last modified" timestamp on files.  I'm sure this has been done before. I suspect answers will direct me to these existing solutions :-). But this question is really specific. I need to have a way to say "if there is already an existing LMod line, do such-and-such, otherwise do something else. I can't figure out an ex commandline that would treat a match as a boolean. Can someone steer me in the right direction?
FWIW, my stamps look like this:
" Last modified: Sun Jun 02 2024 08:18:50 PM -04:00 [EDT]

My regexp is suitably ugly, so ugly it's beautiful:
/\%>0l^[\"\#\/] Last modified: \%<7l

UPDATE: the match() function will probably do what I need. It returns -1 if no match is found, otherwise it returns the index of the starting character of the match.

If you found a solution, please consider writing up your own answer (and accepting it) so people who encounter similar challange could find here the answer and learn from your experience
